# what is difference using = and : in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 var app = new Vue({
 el: '#main',
 template: $("#products-template").text(),
 data: {
loading: true,
products: []
},
ready: function() {
var self = this;
$.getJSON(url, function(fbresults){
self.products = fbresults.data;
self.loading  = false;
});
}
});
```

and

```
var app = new Vue({
el= '#main',
template= $("#products-template").text(),
data= {
loading= true,
products= []
},
ready= function() {
var self = this;
$.getJSON(url, function(fbresults){
self.products = fbresults.data;
self.loading  = false;
});
}
});
```

In the above code snippets '=' as well as ':' are used , so when do we need to use = and when to use : , what is the purpose of : mainly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon here is used when declaring properties of an object literal:

```
{
    key: value,
    key2: value2
}
```

The equals operator assigns a value to a variable or expression:

```
foo = 5;
obj.key = value;
```

In your example, the colons are defining properties of the object passed into `Vue`. It's much more obvious if you use proper indentation:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    template: $("#products-template").text(),
    data: {
        loading: true,
        products: []
    },
    ready: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON(url, function(fbresults){
            self.products = fbresults.data;
            self.loading  = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`:` assigns values within an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects), `=` assigns values outside of an object literal.

For example:

```
// at this point we're outside of an object, so we use =
var hello = "world";

var someObject = {
    // now we're inside an object literal definition, so we use :
    hello: "world"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can understand this with a simple example:

```
var x = {
    obj1: 'text1', //declaring properties of an object literal
    obj2: 'text2'
};
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
var y = new Object();
obj1.a = 'text1';  //assigning a value to the expression
obj2.b = 'text2';
```